# How to release R's prompt when using 'system'?

Tags: r

I am writing an R code on a Linux system using RStudio. At some point in the code, I need to use a `system` call to a command that will download a few thousand of files from the lines of a text file:

```
down.command <- paste0("parallel --gnu -a links.txt wget")

system(down.command)
```

However, this command takes a little while to run (a couple of hours), and the R prompt stays locked while the command runs. I would like to keep using R while the command runs on the background.

I tried to use `nohup` like this:

```
down.command <- paste0("nohup parallel --gnu -a links.txt wget > ~/down.log 2>&1")

system(down.command)
```

but the R prompt still gets "locked" waiting for the end of the command.

Is there any way to circumvent this? Is there a way to submit system commands from R and keep them running on the background?

Comment: R has limited built-in support for this but the [‘processx’ package](https://processx.r-lib.org/) makes this effortless.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @KonradRudolph. The `processx` package solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ‘processx’, here’s how to create a new process that redirects both stdout and stderr to the same file:

```
args = c('--gnu', '-a', 'links.txt', 'wget')
p = processx::process$new('parallel', args, stdout = '~/down.log', stderr = '2>&1')
```

This launches the process and resumes the execution of the R script. You can then interact with the running process via the `p` name. Notably you can signal to it, you can query its status (e.g. `is_alive()`), and you can synchronously wait for its completion (optionally with a timeout after which to kill it):

```
p$wait()
result = p$get_exit_status()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by @KonradRudolph, I became aware of the `processx` R package that very smartly deals with system process submissions from within R.

All I had to do was:

```
library(processx)

down.command <- c("parallel","--gnu", "-a", "links.txt", "wget", ">", "~/down.log", "2>&1")

processx::process$new("nohup", down.comm, cleanup=FALSE)
```

As simple as that, and very effective.

Comment: Do you actually *need* the `nohup`? Does the child process outlive the calling R process?

Comment: Yes, I think I do. The process needs to be running while the rest of the R code (quite a long one) goes on.

Comment: That in itself doesn’t require `nohup`: `process$new` immediately returns, it does *not* wait for the process to complete. In fact, you’d probably want to assign the resulting process object to a variable so that you can interact with the process (e.g. wait for its completion). In fact, the redirection is also dodgy: this shouldn’t work at all.

Comment: Right, I agree. And I just figured that I can also use `stdout` and `stderr` to direct outputs and errors to specific files. Definitely `nohup` is needless for my use case.